# Is there was to apply a NEW Avro schema to an existing schema in Nifi without infering order?

Tags: schema, apache-nifi, avro

I am using Nifi to load CSVs, apply a NEW schema and load them into a SQl db. Currently I am writting an Avro schema, and applying the schema to each CSV. I am writing the schema based on the order of the incoming CSV- the first field = first column in CSV. Is there a way to map one schema to another based on column name? I.e. can I say 'csv.name -> sql.username'.

I know this can be done manually before uploading the csvs, I am wondering if there is a way within Nifi to map a schema to data based on the datas current schema, not knowing the order of the current schema, just the fields.

I have read about recordpaths and update records. I am looking for something to match the whole incoming schema to a new schema, not based on order.

Avro Schema Settings:

[image: AvroSchema settings]

PutDatabaseRecord settings

[image: PutDatabaseRecord settings]

Comment: If you are loading those files into a DB, the order of the columns usually doesn't matter. What processor are you using to insert them into the DB and what kind of DB do you use?

Comment: "GetFile->PutDatabaseRecord"  I am aplying an Avro Schema before PutDataBaseRecord. Using mssql db. I am having trouble with the AvroSchema neededing to be mapped to the data in a specific order, not the data to the db.

Comment: Could you provide the processor in which you apply the Avro shema with, its configuration, and more importantely, its AvroReader/Writer configuration?

Comment: @BenYaakobi I am not having problem with the current configuration, I am just looking to apply the schema without having to follow the current files order. Below is an example schema. I will attach screen shots of the configurations. `{
 "namespace": "nifi",
 "name": "test",
 "type": "record",
 "fields": [
  { "name": “field1",  "type": ["null","string"] },
  { "name": "field2",  "type": ["null","string"]},
  { "name": "field3",  "type": ["null","string"] }
 ]
}
`

Comment: @BenYaakobi this is a similar question, but with a different application of the schema. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45852910/avro-schemas-not-compatible-if-field-order-changes. The only solution I have found so far is to use execute script and write custome code to map the new schema to the old schema based on column name, not order.

Comment: Order of fields doesn't matter in Avro, so you should be using names anyway

Comment: are you enforcing this schema on purpose? or did you just fill the schema registry because it required you to?
@cricket_007 it's not really accurate. Avro requires the schema written into the file and the required schema to be *exactly* the same. It means, that if you changed the order of the fields, then the schemas are not exactly equal. So without a header line to guide the mappings, it would not know how to map which value to which column.

Comment: @Ben The reader and writer can be separate. If both data types are records, then fields are resolved by name, and ordering can be different. https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Schema+Resolution

Comment: @cricket_007 thats a good doc. My problem is the new schema does not match on name or type. I need to manually input a mapping of the new schema to the current schema.

Comment: Yeah, but how would it know which field to map without a header line?

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you have two options:

**Option 1(better one):**
Add a header line to your records and set `Treat First Line as Header` to `True` in your `CSVReader`

**Option 2:** 
Set `Schema Access Strategy` in your `CSVReader` to `Infer Schema`(available since NiFi 1.9.0)

The first one can guarantee a correct mapping of your fields their types.

Comment: this does not answer my question. I know how to infer or grab a schema from a csv. I am wanting to map a new schema onto the current schema- not based on the order of the current schema.

Comment: then your question is not explained good enough.. Please add to your question more details about the schema you have, the new schema you want to apply and what the original and the destination formats are.

Comment: All of those details are shared in the question- just updated. I am wanting to apply a new schema- manually typing the schema in as a header in the csv does not solve the problem within nifi.

Comment: Please provide the old and new Schema you want to apply. If you don't want to share them, you can change the name of the fields, keeping the types only.